# Designing the Scipmylo - The Low-jump

Tags: humans, anatomy, sports

This is a follow-up to [The running-backwards Olympics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/the-running-backwards-olympics)

The designer of the backwards Olympics (aka The Scipmylo) is making good progress but there are some difficulties with the Low-jump.

To be a valid event it must have a measurable element of jumping, so the limbo is not suitable. At the moment the idea is to jump under a high-jump type bar and gradually lower it as the competition continues.

One suggestion is to see who can jump the longest distance at each given height.

As we all know, high jumpers are quite lanky and long jumpers have to be good sprinters.

What sort of physique is optimum for the low-jump and can anyone suggest an equivalent of the 'Fosbury Flop' for this event? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fosbury_Flop

Note: There is a problem with open-endedness with the event as currently defined. With the high-jump it can be made higher and higher indefinitely. Clearly no-one can jump under a bar that is lower than their height - or can they?

Comment: Why not better jumping backwards after running backwards, too? That would leave the open-endedness. Or starting a race with all the runners sitting on the sand, who have to stand and jump with a single movement when the start is given.

Comment: Would the limbo count if you *jump* under it? I imagine getting an optimally flat trajectory on a jump would be rather difficult.

Comment: I would also advise the judges/refs, to place a second bar or marker of some sort on the floor to ensure that no contact was made with the floor during transit beneath the low jump bar

Comment: @Cadence, that's a fabulous idea!  Think about a baseball player sliding into second.  How low can you go?  You can't impact the posts holding the horizontal rod.  Suck in the belly?  And the chest (exhale just before you go under)!  Turn your head to the side.  Knees!  Worry about your knees!  I really like your idea.

Comment: I imagined the reverse olympic jumping sports to be falling sports - tests to see who can fall the longest fall without getting hurt.

Comment: As I think through this, it can't be a traditional jump of any kind. Even your suggestion about distance-at-height doesn't work. That's just the fastest runner with the longest stride.  And how do you judge if they "jumped" too high?  There should still be a skill being tested and a way to fail the test.  Theoretically, it should also have a basis in need, such as the military value of running/jumping/throwing weapons or bull riding/cattle roping.  What's the value of shuffling your feet?  Maybe stealth?  In that case, you need a sand pit and you judge how much sand is kicked up by the runner.

Comment: Wait... I just contradicted myself.  Your distance-at-height idea does work with the sand pit thing.  Giggle.

Comment: @ JBH - Jumping too high is judged by whether or not they knock the bar off: just as in the current high-jump.

Comment: @Renan - That's a really good idea. Instead of the high jump have falling from a height. I'm not sure how that would work for the long-jump though.

Comment: You don't make it a long jump, you make it a short jump.  See who can land closest to the wall off which you're jumping without touching it.  Remember that (thanks in part to the spin of the Earth and the force of your jump), falling objects move in a parabolic motion (oh, call it *ballistics*).  This means one must intelligently overcome that natural effect with precision.  I think @Renan's on to something.

Comment: Also, jumping too high being judged by knocking off a bar means knocking it off with your head, right?

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/134664/

Answer (score 4):

This us going to be silly to an extreme, but it's the effect of starting off with a silly premise.

Don't judge who jumps the lowest, judge who falls the furthest.

I can only thing of one non-Jackass way for people to do it without getting hurt (too much). Have people bungee jump from a bridge into a pool of mud. You can then measure how deep they went by measuring the length of dirty rope, and the fact that it's mud disencourages people from cheating by trying to swim down.

Comment: I like this idea. However, based on your idea, I think I'd prefer for people simply to jump off a higher and higher platform onto a 1 inch layer of rubber. This way it is both a test of courage and landing technique.

Answer (score 4):

You could make it into a competition of jumping through hoops. Have a look at [this short video](https://youtu.be/DhRcY8EpaVs).

The competition starts with a hoop of large diameter that stands on the ground. The athlets have to jump through. In each round the diameter of the hoop gets smaller, so the athlets have to jump lower and lower.

Answer (score 3):

This is both complicated, and simple... as both RL competitions require fairly lanky builds, as it stands this relies far more upon the rules for the jump then the build.

Long Jump and High Jump don't technically require a running start, however to optimise the distance it is most beneficially to do so, now the low jump would probably change its optimal body type dependent on if it was a standing jump, or running jump, and also if the competitor must land on on their feet...

- Standing jump onto Feet then shorter low centre of gravity jumpers would be able to jump a short distance and then right themselves better than and taller higher centre of gravity individual.
- Standing Jump onto hands, in a some form of diving position, then a taller lanky and springier (is that even a word?) athlete would be superior
- Running start onto Feet would probably benefit the taller at the start and then shorter as the bar lowers, again due to the need to right onesself
- Running start onto Hands, then again a slimmer lanky tall build is most suited

*Of course, perhaps the running diving start onto hands, then break dance flip thing over into a cartwheel followed by a front/back flip would probably be closer to the reverse triple jump then the low jump... but i digress*

Answer (score 3):

The ancient low-jump competition involves a bar *set on fire*. The goal is to jump as close as possible to the bar without going over the bar and without getting burned. Modern competitions just use a bar with sticky substance on it to mark a competitor who touches. The bar is lowered over successive rounds until the competitors are diving under a bar. You cannot touch the ground under the bar for one meter on either side of the bar.

This means the optimal competitors are sprinters — thin and able to get a burst of speed for the dive.